# Pylint false positive when unpacking sys.argv

Tags: python, pylint

I have a script where I unpack `sys.argv` into a function, like so:

```py
import sys


def do_something(a, b):
    """
    It doesn't matter what this function does.
    """
    print(a + b)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_something(*sys.argv[1:])
```

When I execute the script, everything works fine (of course, in my real script I make sure that there are enough args).

The problem is when I run this script through **pylint version 2.6.0, with python 3.8.1**, I get the following error:

```
************* Module script
script.py:12:4: E1120: No value for argument 'a' in function call (no-value-for-parameter)
script.py:12:4: E1120: No value for argument 'b' in function call (no-value-for-parameter)
```

Which is an error that does not appear when using a lower version of **pylint (1.9.5) with python 2.7.18**

I have tried unpacking `sys.argv` in an intermediary variable, but the pylint error did not change.

Does anybody know if there is a way for me to fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this will fail if `len(sys.argv) != 3`. `pylint` can't assume that the proper command-line arguments will be provided.

You can use:

```
if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
    a, b = sys.argv[1:]
    do_something(a, b)
else:
    echo "Usage: python scriptname a b"
```