# Python list unpacking trigger pylint ' No value for argument' warning

Tags: python, list, pylint

This question is the same as [Pylint false positive when unpacking sys.argv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64496832/pylint-false-positive-when-unpacking-sys-argv) but it had no answer.

I have the following function:

```
def join(*paths_to_join: str) -> str:
    """Join and returns a normalized path

    Args:
        *paths_to_join (str): All paths to be joined, as an arbitrary number of strings

    Returns:
        The normalized joined path
    """

    return os.path.normpath((os.path.join(*paths_to_join))
```

This triggers the following `pylint` warning:

> E1120: No value for argument 'a' in function call
> (no-value-for-parameter)

Is it a real warning or a false positive ? Can I do something else than disable it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid warning. `os.path.join()` requires at least one argument, but your function doesn't. So `paths_to_join` could be empty.

Change your function to be similar to `os.path.join()`

```
def join(first: str, rest: List[str]): -> str:
    return os.path.normpath(os.path.join(first, *rest))
```

Comment: You are right, what is interesting is that I did unit test the function using single parameters and it's working

Comment: I replaced by normalize(os.path.join(paths_to_join[0], *paths_to_join[1:]))

But to be honest I like it less because it forces me to check the length of the list and raise appropriate exceptions when previously os.path.join was doing that for me.